# Mails not sent in production side rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp

I have a rails app with one form. After saving that form all data will be send in an email id. Form is working great in development side. But after deploying the app it doesn't work. It's giving the following error in the browser.

```
                  We're sorry, but something went wrong.

      If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

In this application I have another contact us form. That form work fine after deployment in production side.

Comment: what is the output of your `application/path/log/production.log`?

Comment: there are only one log file development.log

Comment: Your question title told that you're facing problem in production mode. So, there must be a production.log file.

Comment: I have another contact us form.That work fine in both side

Comment: Please add the logs, by your comments I guess you are still using the development environment variables in production.